# How to create an Azure WebJob using terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

I am looking for an example on how to create an Azure Webjob inside an Azure Webapp in Azure but I was no able to find anything online. Does anyone know how to create one?

Comment: Have you found a way of doing this except my way?

Answer (score 1):

When Terraform definitions **do not exist** for Azure resources, you can utilize `azurerm_template_deployment` to deploy ARM templates.

For your case, looks like the [WebJob ARM template](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/master/ARMTemplates/WebAppWithWebJobs.json) can be deployed by [azurerm_template_deployment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/template_deployment.html).

Comment: Sure, but in that case the resources created will not be managed by terraform. I would like a more elegant solution.